# Read a complex txt file (includes arrays) to Python

Tags: python, regex, parsing, text-files

I have a txt file that one of its columns includes arrays- every row has a different sized array as this column’s value (the array has strings inside, separated by comma and defined by quotes). Here's a sample:

```
   Color  Count People
0   Red   2     ["Ben", "Mike"]
1  Blue   0     []
2  Yellow 3     ["Ben", "Mike", "Tom"]
```

I want to work on this file with Pandas as a data frame.
I have tried many ways including regex to read the file but without success.

I think I may have to read it line by line and build a table iteratively but I am not sure how.

Would be grateful for suggestions

Comment: Without some sort of sample don't expect much help.

Comment: @hpaulj thank you for the comment, I have inserted a sample

Comment: what do you want to do with arrays? Split to rows? Remove ? Something else? Maybe show expected result.

Comment: does this file delimitted by tab or just spaces?

Comment: @PhungDuyPhong tab

Comment: @furas I would like to run a segmentation analysis on the data frame so I'm still debating what the best method will be, I think perhaps separate to different columns or leave as an array

Comment: Because it is tab delimited, use `read_table( 'data.txt', sep ='\t')` and then you can then you can use `separator.py` to push each item in the listed column into a row here is the function: https://gist.github.com/jlln/338b4b0b55bd6984f883

Comment: @user11395824 "I have a txt file that one of its columns includes arrays" No, a text file contains *text*. By the looks of it, this is simply someone writing the results of `str(df)` on some dataframe to a file and calling it serialization. But it wasn't meant for that, next time you should use one of the many existing serialization formats, in this case, `pickle` would have done fine.

Comment: you are welcome!

Comment: @sconfluentus thank you! that worked! I'm debating how I should deal with this array that has now been imported as a string. I would like not to push each item to a row, but perhaps make it a numpy array or another method that I can apply statistical calculations on after. Do you perhaps have a suggestion? Thank you again

Comment: You can save an array or list or set in a dataframe cell, and leave it where it is.

Answer (score 0):

Your sample looks a lot like the display of a pandas dataframe.  Saving such a frame to csv has some of the same problems, though maybe simpler.  I recently responded to a similar case, different in that the lists were replaced with numpy arrays.

Anyways, let's try a simpler recreation.

Define a dictionary:

```
In [77]: {'Color':'Red', 'Count':2, 'People':['Ben','Mike']}                                              
Out[77]: {'Color': 'Red', 'Count': 2, 'People': ['Ben', 'Mike']}
In [78]: pd.DataFrame([_])                                                                                
Out[78]: 
  Color  Count       People
0   Red      2  [Ben, Mike]
```

Or with 3 rows:

```
In [79]: pd.DataFrame([_77,_77,_77])                                                                      
Out[79]: 
  Color  Count       People
0   Red      2  [Ben, Mike]
1   Red      2  [Ben, Mike]
2   Red      2  [Ben, Mike]
```

If we write that to a csv:

```
In [80]: df = pd.DataFrame([_77,_77,_77])                                                                 
In [81]: df.to_csv('stack59675154.txt')                                                                   
In [82]: cat stack59675154.txt                                                                            
,Color,Count,People
0,Red,2,"['Ben', 'Mike']"
1,Red,2,"['Ben', 'Mike']"
2,Red,2,"['Ben', 'Mike']"
```

this like your csv, except is uses a comma delimiter, and quotes the lists.  It is actually saving the print string of the list, `str(['Ben', 'Mike'])`.

pandas can read this:

```
In [83]: data = pd.read_csv('stack59675154.txt')                                                          
In [84]: data                                                                                             
Out[84]: 
   Unnamed: 0 Color  Count           People
0           0   Red      2  ['Ben', 'Mike']
1           1   Red      2  ['Ben', 'Mike']
2           2   Red      2  ['Ben', 'Mike']
In [85]: data['People'][0]                                                                                
Out[85]: "['Ben', 'Mike']"
```

But the `People` column actually contains strings, not lists.  Fortunately the strings can be `eval`:

```
In [86]: eval(_)                                                                                          
Out[86]: ['Ben', 'Mike']
```

There's a safer string evaluator, but I won't get into that.

`0,Red,2,"['Ben', 'Mike']"` without the quotes, the reader would have problems, since it will see the delimiter inside the brackets.  The simple `numpy.genfromtxt` reader can even handle those quotes.  Simple readers just use `line_list = line.split(delimiter)`, getting a list of strings, one for each 'column'.

I believe the reader(s) in the `csv` module can be instructed to handle nesting quotes, and maybe even nesting brackets.